# Database design: Better to store more columns or use a single column with a dictionary on Backend?

Tags: sql, mongodb, backend, database

I'm building a web app which takes preferences and saves them.

The dataset I want to save will consist of a unique ID, a search string and some finite list of parameters which could be represented as True or False. This list of parameters could get up to say 10 in number.

I haven't decided what type of database I'm using but assuming it has rows and columns, would it be more efficient to have ID, search string and all the parameters as separate columns OR would it be more efficient to have ID, search string and then a single column representing all my parameters using some sort of dictionary that I would translate on the back end.

For example I could represent option A, C and D as A-C-D in a single column and then use a dictionary on retrieval to work with it in the application. Or else I would be using ColA: True, ColB: False, ColC: True, ColD: True, ..., ColN in the table and working with that when I pull it through

Would it be more useful to choose an SQL style DB over something like MongoDB in either case?

Comment: Neither.  It's more efficient to have a separate table that has `DataSetID, Param` which you could insert as many parameters to as you desire, and `JOIN` to that table to get your params.  There are plenty of examples/tutorials for this online.

Comment: Isn't that what I suggested? Is `Param` a single column or multiple?

Comment: One sec, I'll post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this depends.  Normally, one uses relational databases to store relational information.  This would mean that you have separate columns for options and values.  There are traditionally two ways of doing this.

The most common is a normalized form, where each option has a column in a `Users` table.  The key is the user id and you can just read the values.  This works very well when there is a finite list of options that doesn't change much.  It is also really useful when you want to query the table by options -- which users have a particular option, for instance.

Another method is called entity-attribute-value (EAV).  In this method, the `UserOptions` table would have a separate row for each user and each option.  The key would normally consist of the user/option pair (and the option itself might be an id that references a master list of options).  This is flexible; it is easy to add values and it can handle an unlimited number of options per user.  The downside is that getting all options for a user can be cumbersome; there is no data type validation on the values; implementing check constraints to validate values is tricky.

A third method can be useful for some purposes.  That is to store all the options in a single "string" -- more typically, a JSON object.  This is useful when you are using the database only for its ACID properties and don't need to query individual options.  You can read the "options object" into your application, and it parses them into the options.

And, these are three examples of methods of solving the problem.  There are also hybrid approaches that combine elements from more than one solution.

Which solution works best for you depends on your application.  If you just have a handful of predetermined options, I would go with the first suggestion, a single column per option in a table.

Comment: So given that I need to get every option at once because I'm building an API call based on the combination of parameters I've stored, I should be using option 1 or possibly option 3 (this sounds like what I mentioned in the description?). Very useful answer with a good overview, thank you

Comment: @darkace . . . You have just a handful of columns and all need to be populated.  Use the first option -- one column per value.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the two options you specified is ideal.

> Would it be more efficient to have ID, search string and all the parameters as separate columns

The problem with this is not only does this assume that you have a fixed maximum number of parameters, but querying this data would require you to always include every param column.  An example query for this would be like this:

```
SELECT    Id, <other fields>, Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, ..., Param10
FROM      YourTable
WHERE     <stuff>
```

This can be very cumbersome on the back-end trying to check for `NULL` values, and you may run into the situation where you don't have enough columns.  Plus, indexing would be very high overhead to add an index to each Param.

In short, don't do that method.

> OR would it be more efficient to have ID, search string and then a single column representing all my parameters using some sort of dictionary that I would translate on the back end.

Also, no.  There is a large problem with this method when it comes to querying data.  If, say, you wanted to retrieve all records with parameter `xyz`, you would need to construct a query that parses out all of the params and compares them.  Such a query cannot be indexed, and performance will be dreadful.  In addition, it requires *more* coding on the application layer to actually make sense of the data returned.

> Proposed Solution

You should make a separate table for the parameters.  The structure would look something similar to this:

```
Dataset:                    DatasetParameters:
    Id                          DatasetId
    <Other Fields>              Parameter
```

Using this structure, let's say for `ID` 1, you have parameters `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.  You can insert into the `DatasetParameters` four columns:

```
DatasetId    Parameter
----------------------
1            A
1            B
1            C
1            D
```

If you want to add more parameters later, you can simply insert (or delete, should you wish to remove) from this table with the `DatasetId` being the `ID` of the `Dataset` table.

To query this, all you would need to do is use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT      D.*, P.Param
FROM        Dataset       D
INNER JOIN  DatasetParam  P  ON  D.ID = P.DatasetID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should clarify that the combination of all my options will build together to determine parameters in an API call so I think it's more efficient to get them in a single row. Found your explanation helpful though!